# Large infinitary logical theories/systems

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

This question is (necessarily) somewhat vague/imprecise, but I'm hoping that I can get some insight into it. Suppose we are working in the infinitary first-order language $\mathcal{L}_{\infty, \infty}$ in which we can have proper classes of function and relation symbols of arbitrarily high (not necessarily finite) arity, as well as infinitary conjunctions and disjunctions of arbitrary size. Suppose we set up a logical "system" $\mathcal{T}$ couched in this infinitary language, in which one has a proper class of axioms (given by sentences of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty, \infty}$) and a proper class of inference rules (allowing you to deduce sentences of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty, \infty}$ from certain classes of sentences of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty, \infty}$), where some of the inference rules may have proper classes of hypotheses. *A priori* it doesn't seem likely that one could define a (well-behaved) notion of *proof* for such a logical system $\mathcal{T}$, because such a "proof" of a sentence of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty, \infty}$ from the axioms and inference rules of $\mathcal{T}$ might involve a proper class of steps. But is there any way to make sense of a (well-behaved/defined) notion of proof for such a large logical system? Could one perhaps invoke Grothendieck universes in some fashion?

Edit: I am also interested in the case where we only have a *set* of axioms, and each inference rule only has a *set* of hypotheses, which may make things better behaved. So we may still have a proper class of inference rules, but we only have a set of axioms, and each individual inference rule only has a set of hypotheses.

Comment: It may help demystify things to consider the "infinite/finite" analogue of the "class/set" situation you describe. Namely, consider a situation where we have a logic $\mathcal{L}$ whose individual sentences are finite objects but where some of the inference rules are infinite-arity and then try to describe $\mathcal{L}$-provability in a finite framework.  A lot of the issues will be the same. For example, this happens if we try to talk about $\omega$-logic (= $\mathsf{FOL}$ in the language of arithmetic + the $\omega$-rule) inside the natural numbers: we can do so but only to a certain extent.

Comment: In both settings, we can quantify over "large" (= class-sized, or infinite) sets *of a fixed bounded complexity* (w/r/t the Levy or arithmetical hierarchies as appropriate), and so get a notion of "$\Sigma_n$-provable" (or "$\Sigma^0_n$-provable"). On the other hand, Tarski's undefinability theorem poses problems for doing much better than this (e.g. looking at the infinite/finite example above, we have that "provable in $\omega$-logic" = "true in $\mathbb{N}$").